# Footage of Space Shuttle astronauts during launch and reentry

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, space-shuttle, humans, physical-activity, crew-module

Is there readily available video of Space Shuttle missions showing the crew:

1. During the entire time period from ignition to shortly after the shuttle has passed through planet Earth's atmosphere?
2. During the entire time period just before reentry to just after landing?

I have interviewed multiple astronauts from Space Shuttle missions, and they thought such footage should be available on NASA's website, but I have yet to find it.

Does anyone know if such footage exists, and where it is located? If not, does anyone know why NASA does not make it available?

*(Note that I am also interested in similar footage from all other spacecraft starting from the first human spaceflight (Vostok 1) until present.)*

Comment: It should be relatively easy to find footage of the STS-135 entry inside the cabin; this was widely shown during the accident investigation. I do not have access to good technology right now so I can't look myself.

Comment: FYI,a Space Shuttle reentry video spanning from reentry to landing would be over 40 minutes long....just sayin'.

Comment: @Digger Yes, the longer the footage, the better.

Answer (score 4):

There's loads of them, use e.g. [Google's video search](https://www.google.com/videohp) with some related search terms like *[space shuttle inside cabin launch landing](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=space+shuttle+inside+cabin+launch+landing&tbm=vid)*. This returned for example:

... and so on. Replace search term to find videos from inside the crew cabin of other launch vehicles. Happy viewing! :)

Comment: We should not be sending our readers to external sites by telling them to google things. This is in practice a link-only answer, with one of its two links being already broken.